# Export Contacts after Include/Exclude Search: Selection of Fields not possible

Tags: drupal, 4.6.2

After doing an Include/Exclude Search I want to export the contacts found, so I select "Export Contacts" from the "Actions"-drop down menu.

However there is no possibility to select the contact-fields I want to export, there is just the CiviCRM_Contact_Search.csv file generated containig the following fieldes: "Contact ID","Contact Type","Name","Group Name".

Is this on purpose, a missing feature or a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Missing feature I would suspect. Can you step around it by just adding the contacts from your search result to (yet another) Group, then Export from the standard Search?

Comment: Sure, my workaround is to give them a temporary tag and use simple search... a bit complicated. What worries me most, is that I would expect the same behaviour of the software in similar situations.